# How can one disable supported crypto groups in Firefox's TLS support

Tags: firefox, browser, web, tls, cryptography

I know how to enable/disable a particular cryptosuite in Firefox, with the settings like `security.ssl3.rsa_des_ede3_sha` in `about:config`. But I can't find how to do that with supported field groups, such as secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072.

A web search didn't yield anything useful either.

Anybody has a pointer for that?